# How do I setup React?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, browserify

Please, I just want to start learning React, but I am not sure how to install it. Browserify was recommended but I have never used it before so I am confused.

After this command: `npm install --save react react-dom babelify babel-preset-react`, what do I do next? How do I create a folder and start using React? And what does this other command mean, `browserify -t [ babelify --presets [ react ] ] main.js -o bundle.js`?

Comment: the browserify command is saying -> browserify transform everything in main.js using babelify (babel) with the react preset (so convert jsx to js), output it to bundle.js

Comment: This question may be closed.  It seems like you are soliciting advice from the user community, which is already documented in a book or through training tutorials.  What specifically were you trying to follow that is not working for you?  What have you tried? (note: this may not be the proper forum for you to post your question; which is why it will probably be closed)

Comment: Thank you all, I was simply confused about installing with browserify as I know nothing about it. I guess I would try to learn browserify but for now I simply downloaded the react kit and I have started with that.

Comment: @ifeoluwaking Can you please select an answer and mark it as correct?

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to execute the below command,

```
npx create-next-app
```

After you need to execute the second command,

```
npm run start
```

Answer (score 0):

I just set this up myself on CentOS7, so, I thought I would share the knowledge.

**--Install React:**

```
sudo npm install -g create-react-app
```

**--Assign the "Public" Zone to the Network Interface Used by React in Your Firewall:**

```
firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-interface=eth0
```

**--Open the Port for React in Your Firewall for Development Network:**

```
firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=3000/tcp --permanent
firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=5000/tcp --permanent
```

Note: 3000 is development version, 5000 is production version.

**--Create a React Project:**

```
create-react-app project
```

**--Enter Project Directory and Run NPM:**

```
cd project
npm start
```

**--You will get results like this:**

```
Compiled successfully!

You can now view project in the browser.

    Local:            http://localhost:3000/
    On Your Network:  http://192.168.10.10:3000/
```

Then just load up that URL in a browser.

If you want to learn how to code in React now, then I recommend this tutorial: https://facebook.github.io/react/tutorial/tutorial.html

Comment: Using create-react-app (CRA) is definitely the easiest most painless way to get setup! However, if you require a custom build you may be better off with a custom webpack config (unless you start with CRA as your boilerplate and eject it to further customize)